# MVC5, Entity Framework, Custom registration with encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to .Net and I need your help. I'm using code first approach for my project and I'm trying to build custom register/login with encryption. By some reason I cannot save the user in my database when trying to encrypt the password. Saving the user in the database works when I remove the 2 lines for encryption and salting. Here is my User model:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required !")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name: ")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required !")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name: ")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required !")]
    [EmailAddress]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address: ")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name: ")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required !")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password: ")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords don't match !")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public int AdminCode { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my Register method in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Models.User user)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (AppContext db = new AppContext())
                {
                    var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
                    var encrypPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);

                    //var newUser = db.Users.Create();
                    //newUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                    //newUser.LastName = user.LastName;
                    //newUser.Email = user.Email;
                    //newUser.CompanyName = user.CompanyName;
                    //newUser.Password = encrypPass;
                    //newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
                    //newUser.AdminCode = 0;                       

                    user.Password = encrypPass;
                    user.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

                    db.Users.Add(user);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is not correct");
            }
        return View();
    }
```

[Here is my table.](http://prntscr.com/dalv62). When trying to encrypt I get Error "Validation failed for one or more entities.", but I have no idea what validation is failing. I've checked my DB table and the User model and I don't see the problem. I've really tried to figure it out by my own, but I can't! Any ideas what am I missing ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you're debugging the code in VS and it breaks on an exception, you can see the exception that's thrown in the Locals window and unroll its properties. In this case, look into the EntityValidationErrors property for what *exactly* is failing.

Comment: Don't use entity models as ViewModels. Define a separate ViewModel class for ASP.NET MVC Views and Controller actions, and then map (copy) only needed values between your Entity Model class and the ViewModel class.

Comment: I would guess that ConfirmPassword is causing the validation error. Before calling Add(), try ConfirmPassword = Password;

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I've checked the errors and yes, the problem was in my confirmPassword property. But now I'm a bit confused about in which case you would use the [NotMapped] attribute in your entity model? I understand that EF will not generate columns in the database for properties with that attribute, but I also thought that this attribute will tell EF to ignore this property in general. Isn't that the case ? Why in my case EF is still trying to relate this property to my DB table ? And in which scenario you would use [NotMapped] in your entity model ?